# Yajra datatable customization Laravel 8

Tags: php, laravel, datatables, laravel-8, yajra-datatable

I have some problem in my integration with yajra datatable.

In my code I have parameters (`['dom'=>'Bfrtip', 'buttons' => 'create']`) but this 'dom' make the UI like image below (searchbox, paginate on the left and filter show entries are gone)

[image]

[image]

If I delete 'dom', I get this:

[image]

[image]

How can I fix this? I want add button create aligned with search box and show entries filter for redirecting user to page create with better view (UI) I'm using bootstrap 5. I also want replace text "previous / next" with arrow icons.

Full code: https://pastecode.io/s/utw73bn0

Comment: `'dom'=>'Bfrtip'` tells the datatables to show certain elements on the page, just look in the documentation what each letter for that 'dom' means. Now... your question is mostly related to styling. Find out if datatables is ready for Bootstrap 5. Inspect each element on the page and apply css styling. That will get you in the direction